# How to setup a 16x16 led ( 4x - 8x8 Leds) with 4 shift registers?

Tags: arduino

hey guys I'm confused on how to setup a 16x16 led ( 4x - 8x8 Leds) with 4 shift registers (hcf4094)?

because the one I learned is you use 2 shift registers in one 8x8 LED dot matrix.
but how to do it with 4x - 8x8 Led matrix? 16x16 Basically.

Because when you setup 16x16 led matrix then you have to use 8 registers (2 shift Registers each), that's what ive understand.

But suddenly my professor said that you will only use 4 shift registers in the 16x16 led.

I am confused right now and searching on the net on how to setup but could find what I've need. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you connect two matrices together directly, with no shift registers involved?

Comment: my professor wants shift registers. btw, Im doing Arduino.

Can you check this picture to help me with the simple connection? https://imgur.com/a/C08WD

Comment: Hint : you still only need two shift registers. But each shift register needs to be 16 bits long instead of 8 bits.

Comment: I have 4 8bit shift registers but I'm confused with the connection

Comment: we are not here to do your school work for you. ... you have been given very good hints on the subject, yet your question remains .... talk to your professor. it appears that you do not fully understand how an LED matrix is wired.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the 16x16 array as one whole, not four 8x8 arrays.  One obvious way to multiplex the LEDs is with 16 rows and 16 columns.  If you have 8-bit shift registers, then you need two to control the 16 column lines and two more to control the 16 row lines.

Comment: I am confused with the connection. Can you check this pic Sir? 
Thank you. https://imgur.com/a/C08WD

Comment: i only have 4 shift registers Sir.