# How to implement 16x16 LED DOT Matrix in Proteus

Tags: led, proteus

I am confused on how to implement this circuit to a real one. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

I want to implement the schematic diagram above (1st Pic) to here. How to do it?

Comment: Posible duplicate https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/347065/how-to-setup-a-16x16-led-4x-8x8-leds-with-4-shift-registers

Answer (score 1):

> **How to implement 16x16 LED DOT Matrix ...**

The general solution for translating a circuit diagram into a physical implementation is to read the data sheets for the products involved to determine the pinouts.

Here's part of an example data sheet for [LuckyLight KWM-20882AVB](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/454datasheet.pdf)

[image]
[image]

This shows you the correspondence between pin numbers in the logical circuit diagram and the physical pins on the package.

It is likely that many Chinese manufacturers copy the same implementation.

You can check the pinout with a 3V CR2032 battery (for any other power source use a suitable resistor to limit the current). E.g applying a current-limited 3V coin-cell across pins 9 and 13 should light the corner LED. Try both polarities. Double check by powering other pins and checking the expected LED is illuminated.

If your Four 8x8 devices are laid out like this

```
A B
C D
```

Your top diagram says you want to link pin 13 of C to pin 13 of A. Using the information you have, you can identify where pin 13 is on each and solder a wire between them. Or design a PCB with tracks that link these positions.

Add numbers to the pins in your bottom diagram and draw lines for the wires you need to solder on.

If this is your first electronics project, I suggest you temporarily put it aside, obtain a few discrete LEDS, 470 ohm resistors, 9v battery and breadboard and spend an hour getting comfortable with something simpler before moving on.

> **... in Proteus**

I'm unfamiliar with Proteus but I expect you need to select or import the model for your 8x8 LED-module and then follow the instructions given when you were trained in the use of that software package.

Comment: http://www.tigoe.net/pcomp/code/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/hs-788as-8x8-led.png
this is the one. After I determined it? then what will I do ?

Comment: @Jaddy boy, that link isn't a data sheet. If you know the manufacturer's name and their part-number, you can usually obtain a data-sheet online.

Comment: I really don't understand how this is useful to connect all 4 8x8 together. Sorry I'm just new to electronics... Computer Science major here...

Comment: @JaddyBoy: See edits.

Comment: thank you very for these informations! I will try all of these now

Comment: The best way to express thanks is to upvote any answers you find useful